# centering ul within div (that is already centered on page)

Tags: html, css

I am not able to center ul within div.

HTML:

```
<div id="footer">   <span class="copy">Copyrights 2014</span>

    <ul class="hor_list" id="footer_menu">
        <li><a href="">HOME</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="">SHOPS</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="">CONTACT US</a>

        </li>
    </ul> <a href="" class="footer_link">www</a>

</div>
```

I need `footer_menu` to be in the center. `#footer` is centered in the page, I need footer_menu to be centered within footer.

CSS:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
#footer {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
#footer {
    color: #373737;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.hor_list {
    display: inline-block;
}
.hor_list li {
    display: inline;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
```

Here is working Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WXYx8/

I was trying something like this, not working:

```
#footer_menu {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

EDIT:

I do not need "`span`" and "`a.footer_link`" within footer to be centered (instead those should be very left and very right).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `text-align: center;` to your `#footer`

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WXYx8/1/)

Then You can use float left and float right like this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WXYx8/4/)

```
.copy{
    float: left;
}
.footer_link{
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: I do not need other staff to be cenetered, just ul. I need span to be leftside and a to be rightside.

Answer (score 1):

Add `text-align: center` to the style for the `footer`.

```
#footer {
    color: #373737;
    font-size: 10px;
    height: 24px;
    line-height: 24px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 1000px;
}
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/WXYx8/3/

Answer (score 0):

Try `display: block` instead of `display: inline-block`.
It seemed to do what you are describing on the fiddle.

Comment: The `text-align` solution is probably better.

Comment: If I add block then it pushes "a" to the next row, but it should be floated to the right side.

Answer (score 0):

try this: http://jsfiddle.net/QVykC/

```
<div id="footer">   
<span class="copy">Copyrights 2014</span>
<a href="" class="footer_link">www</a>
<ul class="hor_list" id="footer_menu">
    <li><a href="">HOME</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="">SHOPS</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="">CONTACT US</a>

    </li>
</ul>
```

css

```
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
font-size: 100%;
font: inherit;
vertical-align: baseline;
}
#footer {
text-transform: uppercase;
}
#footer {
color: #373737;
font-size: 10px;
line-height: 24px;
height: 24px;
width: 1000px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
.hor_list {
display: block;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
}
.hor_list li {
display: inline;

}
ol, ul {
list-style: none;
}
#footer_menu {
width: 300px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.copy {
float: left;
}

.footer_link {
float: right;
}
```